# How to match arraylist data in another class in java

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I developed a student class which add students, and in the main class I used arraylist to show all the students that has been added. Now I made a enrolement class and I want to match the ID  that has been entered to the enrolment class does it match to the students that has been added. I am having problem with that, can someone please tell me how to do that ... Putting my code below

This is Mian Class-

```
import java.util.*;


public class StudentRecordSystem {

static ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String option;
    String option1 = "a";//initializing the option a from the main menu
    String option2 = "b";//initializing the option b from the main menu
    String option3 = "c";//initializing the option c from the main menu
    String option4 = "d";//initializing the option d from the main menu
    String option5 = "e";//initializing the option e from the main menu
    String option6 = "f";//initializing the option f from the main menu
    String option7 = "g";//initializing the option g from the main menu
    for(int i=1; i<2; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("========== Main Menu ==========");
        System.out.println("a)Student Admin \nb)Course Admin \nc)Staff Admin \nd)Exit");//printing the main menu options
        System.out.println("Your option: ");//asking the user for option to choose
        Scanner inputOption = new Scanner(System.in);
        option = inputOption.nextLine();//Taking user option

        if(option.equals(option1))
        {
            for(int l=1; l<2; l++){


                System.out.println("========== Student Admin Menu ==========");
                System.out.println("a)Add new Student \nb)List Enrolment Details \nc)Enrol Student \nd)Assign Exemption To a Student \ne)Process Payment \nf)Generate Report \ng)Go Back");//printing the main menu options
                System.out.println("Your option: ");//asking the user for option to choose
                option = inputOption.nextLine();//Taking user option
                if(option.equals(option1))
                {
                    Student st = new Student();
                    list.add(st);
                    l--;//continues the loop
                }
                if(option.equals(option2))
                {
                    for (Student st : list) {
                        System.out.println(st.toString());
                    }
                    l--;//continues the loop
                }
                if(option.equals(option3))
                {
                    String[] courseName = {"Java Programming","Object Oriented Design","Software Testing","J2EE","Software Architecture","Design Patterns"};
                    Course c = new Course(courseName);
                    //c.getCourseName();
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.getCourseName()));
                }
                if(option.equals(option4))
                {
                    System.out.println("Will assign exemption to a  student");
                }
                if(option.equals(option5))
                {
                    System.out.println("Will process payment for the student");
                }
                if(option.equals(option6))
                {   
                    System.out.println("Will Generate Report");
                }
            }
            if(option.equals(option7))
            {
                i--;//continues the loop
            }

        }
        else if(option.equals(option2))
        {
            System.out.println("Will go to course class");
            i--;//continues the loop
        }
        else if(option.equals(option3))
        {
            System.out.println("Will go to staff class");
            i--;//continues the loop
        }
        else if(option.equals(option4))
        {
            System.out.println("Thank You For Using This Program");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error:  The selected option is not Recognised. Try Again...");//Error message if wrong option has been entered
            i--;//continues the loop
        }
    }

}

}
```

This is Student Class-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {

private String studentName;
private String studentId;
private String dob;
private Scanner scan;

//Default Constructor
public Student()
{
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Student Name:");
    studentName = scan.next();//Taking Student Name

    System.out.print("Student ID:");
    studentId = scan.next();//Taking Student ID

    System.out.print("Student Date Of Birth(DD/MM/YY):");
    dob = scan.next();//Taking Student Date of Birth

}

//Constructor
public Student(String newStudentName, String newStudentId, String newDob)
{
    this.studentName = newStudentName;
    this.studentId = newStudentId;
    this.dob = newDob;
}

//Setter Methods
public void setStudentName(String newStudentName)
{
    studentName = newStudentName;
}

public void setStudentId(String newStudentId)
{
    studentId = newStudentId;
}

public void setDob(String newDob)
{
    dob = newDob;
}

//Getter Methods
public String getStudentName()
{
    return studentName;
}

public String getStudentId()
{
    return studentId;
}

public String getDob()
{
    return dob;
}

public String toString() {
    return getStudentName() + "\t" + getStudentId() + "\t" + getDob();
}

}
```

This is enrollment class -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Enrollment {

private String studentId;
private Scanner scan;



public Enrollment()
{
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please Enter The Student ID:");
    studentId = scan.next();


}



}
```

Comment: When the object of Enrollment is created ? It should have list of Student right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `getter` for `studentId` in `Enrollment` class,

```
public String getStudentId(){
    return studentId;
}
```

In your main class, create `Enrollment` object after the `list` is initialized

```
Enrollment enroll = new Enrollment();
```

Iterate over the `ArrayList` to find the match:

```
boolean isfound = false;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    if(list.get(i).getStudentId().equals(enroll.getStudentId()){
        isfound = true;
    }
}
if(isfound){
    System.out.println("Student record found!");
}
else{
     System.out.println("No match found!");
}
```

Comment: its working but I put a else statement as well to show if there is no record or if there is no record has been found. but its only printing the message of it matches, doesnt print the else statement

Answer (score 0):

In your Main create option that the user want to search the student by ID.
And create an object of EnrollmentClass and pass the Arraylist to the contructor.
In the Enrollment class constructor you need to iterate each of the arrayList until youll find the id.

Comment: @user3515895 isn't `Enrollment` class supposed to be an object definition? do the search in your main class